# Reducing same dates with time

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have this array of objects returning from an API;

```
[
    { 
        "startDate": "2023-03-05T08:00:00",
    },
    { 
        "startDate": "2023-03-05T08:15:00",
    },
    { 
        "startDate": "2023-03-05T08:30:00",
    },
    { 
        "startDate": "2023-03-06T11:30:00",
    },
    { 
        "startDate": "2023-03-06T12:00:00",
    },
]
```

I want to combine the same date under a new array of objects such as;

```
[
[
    { 
        startDate: "2023-03-05", 
        time: [{timeSlotId: 8200, formattedTime: '08:00'}, {timeSlotId: 8201, formattedTime: '08:15'}, {timeSlotId: 8202, formattedTime: '08:30'}],
    }, 
    { 
        startDate: "2023-03-06", 
        time: [{timeSlotId: 8300, formattedTime: '11:30'}, {timeSlotId: 8301, formattedTime: '12:00'} ],
    },
]
```

Currently I tried this ;

```
dataAppointments?.slice(0, 10).reduce((acc, appointment) => {
      const { startDate,timeSlotId } = appointment;

      let times;
      if (acc.startDate === moment(startDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')) {
        times = moment(startDate).format('HH:mm');
      }

      return [startDate, [{ time: times }]];
    })
  );
```

But it returns as `["2023-03-05T10:15:00", Array [ Object { "time": "08:00", }, ],` and definitely I am missing something, couldnt place `acc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired result:

```js
const arr = [{
    "startDate": "2023-03-05T08:00:00",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2023-03-05T08:15:00",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2023-03-05T08:30:00",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2023-03-06T11:30:00",
  },
  {
    "startDate": "2023-03-06T12:00:00",
  },
]

const map = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { startDate } = curr;
  const [date, time] = startDate.split("T");
  const [hh, mm, ss] = time.split(":");
  const formattedTime = `${hh}:${mm}`;
  if (!acc.has(date)) {
    acc.set(date, {
      startDate: date,
      time: [formattedTime]
    })
  } else acc.get(date).time.push(formattedTime)
  return acc;
}, new Map());
const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What does the `new Map()` do in the reduce function ? what else could we use here ?

Comment: `Map` is just a data structure to store key-value pair. I've used here because it is created to access fast, if you access frequently. You can use arrays also here...

Comment: This seemed a bit more conveniant. I also now added one more thing to the question, I want to return array of objects there, I tried this `time: [...acc, { timeSlotId: timeSlotId, formattedTime }]` it only returns one object and rest are normal items, what am I doing wrong there ? EDIT: I added `else acc.get(date).time.push({ timeSlotId: timeSlotId, formattedTime }); ` to the else statement, now it returns correcty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple version:

```js
const extractDates = (ss) => Object.entries(ss.reduce (
  (a, {startDate: sd}) => (((a[sd.slice(0, 10)] ??= []) .push (sd.slice(11, 17))), a), 
  {}
)).map(([startDate, time]) => ({startDate, time}))

const starts = [{startDate: "2023-03-05T08:00:00"}, {startDate: "2023-03-05T08:15:00"}, {startDate: "2023-03-05T08:30:00"}, {startDate: "2023-03-06T11:30:00"}, {startDate: "2023-03-06T12:00:00"}]

console .log (extractDates (starts))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Using `reduce` and `slice`, we fold the input into something like this:

```js
{
  "2023-03-05": ["08:00:", "08:15:", "08:30:"], 
  "2023-03-06": ["11:30:", "12:00:"]
}
```

Then we use `Object .entries` to turn that into:

```js
[
  ["2023-03-05", ["08:00:", "08:15:", "08:30:"]], 
  ["2023-03-06", ["11:30:", "12:00:"]]
]
```

and then `map` over those entries to get your final format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```js
let arr = [
    {"startDate": "2023-03-05T08:00:00"},
    {"startDate": "2023-03-05T08:15:00"},
    {"startDate": "2023-03-05T08:30:00"},
    {"startDate": "2023-03-06T11:30:00"},
    {"startDate": "2023-03-06T12:00:00"},
];

let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {startDate}) => {
    let [date, time] = startDate.replace('T', ' ').split(' ');
    (acc[date] ??= {startDate: date, time: []}).time.push({timeSlotId: 0, formattedTime: time.slice(0, 5)});
    return acc;
}, {}));

let fTime = 8199;

res.forEach(ele => {
    ele.time.forEach(ele2 => {
        ele2.timeSlotId = fTime += 1;
    });
    fTime -= ele.time.length;
    fTime += 100;
});
console.log(res);
```